# Wait (not busy) for BroadcastReceiver Intent inside AsyncTask's 'doInBackground'-method

Tags: android, events, android-asynctask, future

Currently I'm trying to wait for an event which is received by a BroadcastReceiver inside an AsyncTask.

The reason is that my bluetooth abstraction does only emit events via Broadcasts/Intents.

```
private static AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> mConnectTask;
private static ManualResetEvent mConnectEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
private static Object mLockConnectTask;

private static final BroadcastReceiver mCustomReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, final Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (ASNYCACTION_CUSTOM.equals(action)) {

            // first try:
            synchronized (mLockConnectTask) {
                mConnectTask.notify();
            }

            // second try:
            mConnectEvent.set();

        }
        // ...
    }
}

private class ConnectToSensorTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        mConnectEvent.reset();
        mLockConnectTask = new Object();

        // start async BT operation
        doAsyncBluetoothOperation();

        try {                       // wait for result
            // first try
            synchronized (mLockConnectTask) {
                wait();             // wait for ever
            }

            // second try
            mConnectEvent.waitOne(5000);    // wait for 5 seconds

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e("ConnectToSensorTask", "error - wait was interrupted.");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

My target is to provide the user an interface like this

```
// interface method to get future to wait for outside
public AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> connectAsync() {
    mConnectTask = new ConnectToSensorTask()
            .executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    return mConnectTask;
}
```

... to use it in this way:

```
// connect to the sensor
mActivity.startProgressBar(R.string.message_connecting);
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> retConnect =
    BluetoothManager.getInstance().connectAsync();
try {
    Boolean isConnected = retConnect.get(PakkcheckManager.TimeoutSec, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    mActivity.stopProgressBar();
    if(isConnected) {
        /// @todo PHIL connect here -> move code from MainFragment.onConnectionStateChanged
        mActivity.showMessageToast("CONNECTED YEAH - TODO REMOVE ME!");
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    mActivity.stopProgressBar();
    mActivity.showMessageToast(R.string.error_unable_to_connect_to_sensor);
}
```

At the first try an exception is thrown:
"java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before wait()"
I thought I would have synchronized it right by using the 'mLockConnectTask' object.
The second try fails because the app waits 5 seconds and executes the connect-process after my AsyncTask-wait method and not before/meanwhile.

What is the best way to wait inside an AsyncTask for an BroadcastReceiver event? Or maybe there is event a way more elegant way to achieve a Future behaviour for the 'user in the code'.

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: "The reason is that my bluetooth abstraction does only emit events via Broadcasts/Intents." -- that is very inflexible choice. And, if you mean system broadcasts, it is wasteful of CPU/memory and possibly is insecure. "What is the best way to wait inside an AsyncTask for an BroadcastReceiver event?" -- you don't. "Or maybe there is event a way more elegant way to achieve a Future behaviour for the 'user in the code'." -- I do not know what that means, sorry. I recommend that you look into other threading patterns, such as RxJava2 and [RxBluetooth](https://github.com/IvBaranov/RxBluetooth).

Comment: With "future behaviour in code" I mean that I would like to use my connect-function like a future from the Fragment/Activity-code. This would be useful to implement clear wait functions ("wait 5 seconds for connect-accomplished and show error message when future-timeout").